Conditions for the invertibility of an Hessenberg matrix
could you tell me what are the conditions for an Hessenberg matrix to be invertible? Could you also provide me a source where I can find the related theorem?
Many thanks!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What are the conditions for an Hessenberg matrix to be invertible?

The conditions are the same as they are for any other matrix.

Thank you. I was wondering if there were simpler conditions for an Hessenberg matrix as, e.g., for lower (upper) triangular ones where the non-zero conditions of the elements on the diagonal is sufficient.
